# eclipse plugin dev: how to open a custom editor from a cnf (on double click).

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, cnf

I'm new to RCP and struggling with how to open a custom editor from a cnf (on double click). I guess it's possible to declare this in plugin.xml, but haven't figured out how.

When i double click on a xml file in my project in cnf I want to open my own custom editor instead of the standard xml editor.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

There is a great tutorial on [Eclipse Editors](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseEditors/article.html#editor_editor) by Lars Vogel that explains this. In essence you define it in plugin.xml with the extension you need. You can use a wizard to create the editor.

Note, when you right click on a file, the *Open with* menu will show all the available editors for that file extension.